# He says he's vegetarian, yet he eats everything put in front of him. What is the use of PUT here?

Tags: ellipsis

> He says he's vegetarian, yet he eats everything **put** in front of
> him.

How has **put** been used here? Could anyone please explain?

Is it possible to say that in the following way?

> He says he's vegetarian, yet he eats everything which is **put** in
> front of him.

Comment: First question: it is past participle form of verb, part of post modifier, which is a past participle clause. Second question: yes possible, where the post modifier is a relative clause.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, you understood correctly. ***Put*** is the past participle of the verb "to put" and it is used in a ***passive reduced relative clause*** modifying the indefinite pronoun ***everything*** (I will put between brackets the omitted part):

> He says he's vegetarian, yet he eats everything ***[which/that is]*** put in front
> of him.

Reduced relative clauses are common in English:

> A ***reduced relative clause*** is a relative clause that is *not marked by an explicit relative pronoun or complementizer* such as ***who, which*** or ***that***. A ***participle*** can often be used instead of a relative pronoun and full verb.
> e.g.
>
> - *Bikes* ***that are ridden*** to school must be left in the bicycle racks. (full relative clause)
> - *Bikes* ***ridden*** to school must be left in the bicycle racks. (participial phrase) ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reduced_relative_clause))

Sometimes, as the Wikipedia article shows, reduced relative clauses can be too ambiguous. But your sentence does not have that sort of ambiguity.

Comment: And in the question's context, it means that he will eat food that _other_ people have served him — but not, presumably, food he has prepared _himself_.  Which may illuminate the bounds of his claimed vegetarianism.

Comment: Correct. If he were the agent of "put", the pronoun _he_ could not be omitted. But then the sentence would not make sense.

Comment: @gidds I don't see anything in the OP sentence that implies he doesn't prep his own food in addition to eating anything others make. Can you expand?

Comment: If you reduce the relative and say, "He says he's vegetarian, yet he eats everything put in front of him.", it is simply obvious that others put that food in front of him. If he were the one who put it, you would need to include "he": _He says he's vegetarian, yet he eats everything **he** put in front of him._ But then the sentence would not make sense, because 1. "put" should be in the present ("puts") and 2. it should be "in front of **himself**, reflexive pronoun needed.

Comment: @Jontia For one thing, there would be no point in specifying ‘put in front of him’ at all, unless it affected the meaning; and it would only do that by restricting the source of food.  And for another, you wouldn't use the passive form if he were placing it in front of himself.  Each of those implies that someone else is putting the food there; taken together, it's highly probable.

Comment: To stir the pot a little: “He says he's vegetarian, yet he eats everything in front of him.” means just about the same as “He says he's vegetarian, yet he eats everything he sees.” or “He says he's vegetarian, yet he eats everything.”   By contrast, “He says he's vegetarian, yet he eats everything ***put*** in front of him.” might be interpreted as “He says he's vegetarian, yet he eats everything put in front of him *by anybody [else].*”, which seems to focus on food presented by others.

Comment: @Scott You've explained what i meant much better!